# ANTLR Grammar for C# List of GUID

Tags: c#, parsing, grammar, antlr4

I am creating a v4 ANTLR Combined Grammar. For list of GUIDs, the expression would be 
['{xxx}','{xxx}','{xxx}']. I am able to parse the stand alone list properly. The errors are when the expression is like

```
({field1} opeartor ['{xxxx}','{yyyy}','{zzzz}']).
```

The relevant portion of the grammar file is:

I have updated Grammar after comment from @damien-the-unbeliever

[Update 1]

```
compilationUnit
: primaryExpression EOF
;
expression
:   booleanOrExpression ( ( ASSIGNFLD | ASSIGN ) booleanOrExpression )* 
;
booleanOrExpression
:    booleanAndExpression  ( OR  booleanAndExpression )*
;
booleanAndExpression
:   equalityExpression ( AND equalityExpression)*
;

equalityExpression
:   relationalExpression ( EQUALITYOPERATORS (relationalExpression)? )*
;
relationalExpression
:   primaryExpression (RELATIONALOPERATORS (primaryExpression)? )*
;
primaryExpression
:   LPAREN expression RPAREN
| valueExpression
;
valueExpression
:   FIELD | NONFIELD
;
NONFIELD
:    VALUELITERAL | LIST 
;
```

[Original]

```
FIELD
: LBRACE StringCharacters RBRACE 
;
LIST
:   LBRACK  ( VALUELITERAL ( COMMA VALUELITERAL)* )+   RBRACK
;
VALUELITERAL
: ( DECIMAL | INTEGER | GUID | STRINGLITERAL )+
;
INTEGER
:   ( DIGIT )+
;
DECIMAL
:   ( DIGIT )* DOT ( DIGIT )+
;
GUID
:   QUOTE LBRACE HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit DASH HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit DASH HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit DASH HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit  DASH HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit RBRACE QUOTE
;
STRINGLITERAL
    :   DBLQUOTE StringCharacters? DBLQUOTE
    ;
fragment HexDigit 
    :     ( DIGIT |'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') 
;
fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9' ;
LPAREN          : '(';
RPAREN          : ')';
LBRACE          : '{';
RBRACE          : '}';
LBRACK          : '[';
RBRACK          : ']';
SEMI            : ';';
COMMA           : ',';
DOT             : '.';
DASH            : '-';
QUOTE           : '\'';
DBLQUOTE        : '"';
```

whilte testing it can parse

```
['{5cd7f294-f30e-4b75-8258-24df4cef86fb}','{263aaab3-4c2b-4779-a34f-fafda877a7be}']
```

but can not parse

```
{field1}includes any['{5cd7f294-f30e-4b75-8258-24df4cef86fb}','{263aaab3-4c2b-4779-a34f-fafda877a7be}']
```

the error is:

```
Result StandardError:   line 1:114 mismatched input ''' expecting {<EOF>, AND, OR, EQUALITYOPERATORS, RELATIONALOPERATORS, ':=', ':= (fld)'}
```

Comment: You say you're showing us the "relevant part" of your grammar, but so far as I can see, *none* of the set of expected symbols are present in the portion that you're showing us - which would tend to imply it's some production that you've not shown us that it thinks it's currently dealing with.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have provided the rest of the file except some operators and other terminals definitions.

Comment: Sorry, just coming back to look at this again. Still not sure entirely what's happening, but one thing that looks out of place, on looking again, are the `+`s in `LIST` and `VALUELITERAL`. Do you really want a `VALUELITERAL` of 123.456.789 (which is a `DECIMAL` 123.456 followed by a `DECIMAL` .789)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Correct. May be I don't need it with `VALUELITERAL`, will change that and check. On `LIST` I do need it to be one or more so `+` is justified there.

Comment: Checked and still the same error.

`Result StandardError:`
`line 1:115 mismatched input ''' expecting {AND, OR, EQUALITYOPERATORS, RELATIONALOPERATORS, ':=', ':= (fld)', ')'}`
`line 1:78 mismatched input ''' expecting {AND, OR, EQUALITYOPERATORS, RELATIONALOPERATORS, ':=', ':= (fld)', ')'}`
`line 1:74 mismatched input ''' expecting {AND, OR, EQUALITYOPERATORS, RELATIONALOPERATORS, ':=', ':= (fld)', ')'}`

Comment: But on `LIST`, that's one or more repeats of `VALUELITERAL (COMMA VALUELITERAL)*` - so if it repeats twice, you get `VALUELITERAL COMMA VALUELITERAL VALUELITERAL COMMA VALUELITERAL` - the inner `*` should already be allowing multiple items in a single list - unless I'm misunderstanding how your lists are meant to work.

Comment: Your grammar doesn't even compile. Rules like `StringLiteral` are not defined, and your input contains the substring `includes any` that would result in lexer errors because no rule can match that sequence of characters.

Comment: @280Z28 `StringLiteral` is taken from Java.g4 from [ANTLR4@Git](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4)

And `includes any` is defined as

    EQUALITYOPERATORS
 : ( INCLUDESANY )
 ;

    INCLUDESANY
 : 'includes any'
 ;